# Define different (than global) CORS policy for WEB API controller in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a global CORS policy defined like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // global cors policy
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
}
```

I must specify the global policy because I am using SignalR.
The policy allows the domain of the website.
In addition, I need to provide a limited number of endpoints for partners that have many different domains.

How do I allow a specific controller to be accessed from any origin (exclude from global policy and add custom policy)?

Comment: It seems you can use attributes to achieve this. Maybe [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enable-cors-with-attributes) from the asp.net core documentation can help you.

Comment: @b2f Yes, but I must set a global policy in Configure, because attributes cannot be used with hidden controllers like SignalR.

Answer (score -1):

In StartUp.cs you could configure cors in `ConfigureService`

```
 readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                                      "http://www.contoso.com");
                              });
        });
    }
```

Then in `Configure` function you could configure the cors per mapped SignlR hub:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCors();
        ...
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            //Map each hub and ad RequireCors per hub
            endpoints.MapHub<EchoHub>("echo")
                .RequireCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Ok. How do I add a different policy for the other controller?